# How to make my TTS not overlap with Google Map voice (for driving direction)?

Tags: android, google-maps, text-to-speech

I am writing an app with TTS, I am able to use UtteranceProgressListener (don't worry about older version on this topic) to gain Audio focus from Music players, and give focus back to Music players after the speech is done.  But the app TTS still overlaps with Google Maps (navigator) voices.

Is there anyway I can tell when Map is speaking, and my voice can be queued, or even flushed (because right now, I cannot discern/understand either of them when both of them are talking).

Or someone can point me to the source of Google Map (or hidden APIs that I can use), I understand that Google map is not part of the Android open source.

Below is snippet of my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
private class utteranceListener extends UtteranceProgressListener {
    private OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
           if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
             // Pause playback
             audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
           } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK){
             //  we don't duck, just abandon focus
             audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
           } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // Resume playback 
           } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
             audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
           }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId)
    {
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void onError(String utteranceId)
    {
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId)
    {
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

    }
}
```

By the way, on music and TTS, I like old-fashion AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT  better than AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK,  a 'ducked' music still makes (TTS) speech hard to listen, especially when playing Rap music, which sometimes is just 'a speech/talk'.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it mostly resolved, with one exception, when Google Map is talking, my code (below) still returns AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED, so I still have overlapping here.

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

On the things that work, two different concepts, **UtterancePrograssListener** is for events *triggered by your own app*, like whenever your speech is done or your speech is about to start; and **OnAudioFocusChangeListener** is for events *triggered by other apps*, like google maps grabbed audio focus from you.

So in case that I want to have my own app stop talking when Google Map is about to announce driving directions, below code would stop my talking:

```
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
   if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
        // Someone else has taken over the audio focus, 
        // abandonAudioFocus() would not do anything.
        // you can only stop(), or lower your voice.
        tts.stop();
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
   } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK){
        //  this is what Google Map actually triggers
        tts.stop();
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
   } 
.....
```